# How to write multi line awk command in the windows?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, awk

I use the `cygwin`, and I want to use the awk command, It works fine if you just write one line `awk` command, but if you want to exec a `multi line cmd`, it will failed,

As the pic bellow,  left side is the result exec `multi line awk cmd` in the **windows** dos window,

and right side is in the `cygwin`, it worked.

how can I fix the issue? Can I exec multi line awk cmd on windows?

[05~06_18-28-06.png http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/05~06_18-28-06.png](http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/05~06_18-28-06.png)

Comment: irrelevant to your problem, on a linux box if I need to write a relatively long/complex command, I type `c-x c-e`

Comment: @Kent mind: blown! That's gonna come in handy :)

Comment: @EdMorton OP says they use cygwin.

Comment: @EdMorton Your interpretation makes sense, but I don't understand the OP's first sentence that way.

Comment: @EdMorton you can answer my question, I will mark your anwser as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard advice: on Windows always put your awk script in a file and execute it as awk -f script.awk to avoid Windows nightmarish quoting rules. If you do that then you also avoid the problem you're currently having. Otherwise, just use cygwin.